# How to add condition in radio buttons in Laravel Blade

Tags: radio-button, conditional-statements, laravel-blade, laravel-5.8

I'm creating a form in laravel, and want to create condition on radio buttons to display relevant input fields. For example, if any one select quantity radio button an input field should appear for entering quantity.

Comment: Could you please add your code so we can see what you have attempted to do

Comment: This can be achieved by jquery/javascript